# For a given set, how to get rid of the some particular set?

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request, sorting

Consider the following decomposition list of $\{a1,a2,a3,a4\}$ into three parts as $t$,

> t={{{a1, a2}, {a3}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a2, a3}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a2}, {a3,
> a4}}, {{a1, a2}, {a4}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a2,
> a4}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a2}, {a4, a3}}, {{a1,
> a3}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a3, a2}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a2,
> a4}}, {{a1, a3}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a3,
> a4}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a4, a2}}, {{a1,
> a4}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a4, a2}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a2,
> a3}}, {{a1, a4}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a4,
> a3}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a3, a2}}, {{a2,
> a1}, {a3}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a1, a3}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a3,
> a4}}, {{a2, a1}, {a4}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a1,
> a4}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a4, a3}}, {{a2,
> a3}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a3, a1}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a1,
> a4}}, {{a2, a3}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a3,
> a4}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a4, a1}}, {{a2,
> a4}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a4, a1}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a1,
> a3}}, {{a2, a4}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a4,
> a3}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a3, a1}}, {{a3,
> a1}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a1, a2}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a2,
> a4}}, {{a3, a1}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a1,
> a4}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a4, a2}}, {{a3,
> a2}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a2, a1}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a1,
> a4}}, {{a3, a2}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a2,
> a4}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a4, a1}}, {{a3,
> a4}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a4, a1}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a1,
> a2}}, {{a3, a4}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a4,
> a2}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a2, a1}}, {{a4,
> a1}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a1, a2}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a2,
> a3}}, {{a4, a1}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a1,
> a3}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a3, a2}}, {{a4,
> a2}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a2, a1}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a1,
> a3}}, {{a4, a2}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a2,
> a3}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a3, a1}}, {{a4,
> a3}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a3, a1}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a1,
> a2}}, {{a4, a3}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a3,
> a2}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a2, a1}}}

Here there are 72 elements, but I want to treat

> {{a1, a2}, {a3}, {a4}} = {{a2, a1}, {a3}, {a4}}, ...

so that the overall element can be reduced to 36

Similarly for $\{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5\}$ into three parts I have my $t$ as

> t= {{{a1, a2, a3}, {a4}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a2, a3,
> a4}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a2}, {a3, a4, a5}}, {{a1, a2}, {a3,
> a4}, {a5}}, {{a1, a2}, {a3}, {a4, a5}}, {{a1}, {a2, a3}, {a4,
> a5}}, {{a1, a2, a3}, {a5}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a2, a3,
> a5}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a2}, {a3, a5, a4}}, {{a1, a2}, {a3,
> a5}, {a4}}, {{a1, a2}, {a3}, {a5, a4}}, {{a1}, {a2, a3}, {a5,
> a4}}, {{a1, a2, a4}, {a3}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a2, a4,
> a3}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a2}, {a4, a3, a5}}, {{a1, a2}, {a4,
> a3}, {a5}}, {{a1, a2}, {a4}, {a3, a5}}, {{a1}, {a2, a4}, {a3,
> a5}}, {{a1, a2, a4}, {a5}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a2, a4,
> a5}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a2}, {a4, a5, a3}}, {{a1, a2}, {a4,
> a5}, {a3}}, {{a1, a2}, {a4}, {a5, a3}}, {{a1}, {a2, a4}, {a5,
> a3}}, {{a1, a2, a5}, {a3}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a2, a5,
> a3}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a2}, {a5, a3, a4}}, {{a1, a2}, {a5,
> a3}, {a4}}, {{a1, a2}, {a5}, {a3, a4}}, {{a1}, {a2, a5}, {a3,
> a4}}, {{a1, a2, a5}, {a4}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a2, a5,
> a4}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a2}, {a5, a4, a3}}, {{a1, a2}, {a5,
> a4}, {a3}}, {{a1, a2}, {a5}, {a4, a3}}, {{a1}, {a2, a5}, {a4,
> a3}}, {{a1, a3, a2}, {a4}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a3, a2,
> a4}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a2, a4, a5}}, {{a1, a3}, {a2,
> a4}, {a5}}, {{a1, a3}, {a2}, {a4, a5}}, {{a1}, {a3, a2}, {a4,
> a5}}, {{a1, a3, a2}, {a5}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a3, a2,
> a5}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a2, a5, a4}}, {{a1, a3}, {a2,
> a5}, {a4}}, {{a1, a3}, {a2}, {a5, a4}}, {{a1}, {a3, a2}, {a5,
> a4}}, {{a1, a3, a4}, {a2}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a3, a4,
> a2}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a4, a2, a5}}, {{a1, a3}, {a4,
> a2}, {a5}}, {{a1, a3}, {a4}, {a2, a5}}, {{a1}, {a3, a4}, {a2,
> a5}}, {{a1, a3, a4}, {a5}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a3, a4,
> a5}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a4, a5, a2}}, {{a1, a3}, {a4,
> a5}, {a2}}, {{a1, a3}, {a4}, {a5, a2}}, {{a1}, {a3, a4}, {a5,
> a2}}, {{a1, a3, a5}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a3, a5,
> a2}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a5, a2, a4}}, {{a1, a3}, {a5,
> a2}, {a4}}, {{a1, a3}, {a5}, {a2, a4}}, {{a1}, {a3, a5}, {a2,
> a4}}, {{a1, a3, a5}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a3, a5,
> a4}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a5, a4, a2}}, {{a1, a3}, {a5,
> a4}, {a2}}, {{a1, a3}, {a5}, {a4, a2}}, {{a1}, {a3, a5}, {a4,
> a2}}, {{a1, a4, a2}, {a3}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a4, a2,
> a3}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a2, a3, a5}}, {{a1, a4}, {a2,
> a3}, {a5}}, {{a1, a4}, {a2}, {a3, a5}}, {{a1}, {a4, a2}, {a3,
> a5}}, {{a1, a4, a2}, {a5}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a4, a2,
> a5}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a2, a5, a3}}, {{a1, a4}, {a2,
> a5}, {a3}}, {{a1, a4}, {a2}, {a5, a3}}, {{a1}, {a4, a2}, {a5,
> a3}}, {{a1, a4, a3}, {a2}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a4, a3,
> a2}, {a5}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a3, a2, a5}}, {{a1, a4}, {a3,
> a2}, {a5}}, {{a1, a4}, {a3}, {a2, a5}}, {{a1}, {a4, a3}, {a2,
> a5}}, {{a1, a4, a3}, {a5}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a4, a3,
> a5}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a3, a5, a2}}, {{a1, a4}, {a3,
> a5}, {a2}}, {{a1, a4}, {a3}, {a5, a2}}, {{a1}, {a4, a3}, {a5,
> a2}}, {{a1, a4, a5}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a4, a5,
> a2}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a5, a2, a3}}, {{a1, a4}, {a5, a2}, {a3}},
> {{a1, a4}, {a5}, {a2, a3}}, {{a1}, {a4, a5}, {a2, a3}}, {{a1, a4,
> a5}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a4, a5, a3}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a5, a3,
> a2}}, {{a1, a4}, {a5, a3}, {a2}}, {{a1, a4}, {a5}, {a3,
> a2}}, {{a1}, {a4, a5}, {a3, a2}}, {{a1, a5,
> a2}, {a3}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a5, a2, a3}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a5}, {a2, a3,
> a4}}, {{a1, a5}, {a2, a3}, {a4}}, {{a1, a5}, {a2}, {a3,
> a4}}, {{a1}, {a5, a2}, {a3, a4}}, {{a1, a5,
> a2}, {a4}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a5, a2, a4}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a5}, {a2, a4,
> a3}}, {{a1, a5}, {a2, a4}, {a3}}, {{a1, a5}, {a2}, {a4,
> a3}}, {{a1}, {a5, a2}, {a4, a3}}, {{a1, a5,
> a3}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a5, a3, a2}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a5}, {a3, a2,
> a4}}, {{a1, a5}, {a3, a2}, {a4}}, {{a1, a5}, {a3}, {a2,
> a4}}, {{a1}, {a5, a3}, {a2, a4}}, {{a1, a5,
> a3}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a5, a3, a4}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a5}, {a3, a4,
> a2}}, {{a1, a5}, {a3, a4}, {a2}}, {{a1, a5}, {a3}, {a4,
> a2}}, {{a1}, {a5, a3}, {a4, a2}}, {{a1, a5,
> a4}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a5, a4, a2}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a5}, {a4, a2,
> a3}}, {{a1, a5}, {a4, a2}, {a3}}, {{a1, a5}, {a4}, {a2,
> a3}}, {{a1}, {a5, a4}, {a2, a3}}, {{a1, a5,
> a4}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a5, a4, a3}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a5}, {a4, a3,
> a2}}, {{a1, a5}, {a4, a3}, {a2}}, {{a1, a5}, {a4}, {a3,
> a2}}, {{a1}, {a5, a4}, {a3, a2}}, {{a2, a1,
> a3}, {a4}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a1, a3, a4}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a3, a4,
> a5}}, {{a2, a1}, {a3, a4}, {a5}}, {{a2, a1}, {a3}, {a4,
> a5}}, {{a2}, {a1, a3}, {a4, a5}}, {{a2, a1,
> a3}, {a5}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a1, a3, a5}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a3, a5,
> a4}}, {{a2, a1}, {a3, a5}, {a4}}, {{a2, a1}, {a3}, {a5,
> a4}}, {{a2}, {a1, a3}, {a5, a4}}, {{a2, a1,
> a4}, {a3}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a1, a4, a3}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a4, a3,
> a5}}, {{a2, a1}, {a4, a3}, {a5}}, {{a2, a1}, {a4}, {a3,
> a5}}, {{a2}, {a1, a4}, {a3, a5}}, {{a2, a1,
> a4}, {a5}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a1, a4, a5}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a4, a5,
> a3}}, {{a2, a1}, {a4, a5}, {a3}}, {{a2, a1}, {a4}, {a5,
> a3}}, {{a2}, {a1, a4}, {a5, a3}}, {{a2, a1,
> a5}, {a3}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a1, a5, a3}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a5, a3,
> a4}}, {{a2, a1}, {a5, a3}, {a4}}, {{a2, a1}, {a5}, {a3,
> a4}}, {{a2}, {a1, a5}, {a3, a4}}, {{a2, a1,
> a5}, {a4}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a1, a5, a4}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a5, a4,
> a3}}, {{a2, a1}, {a5, a4}, {a3}}, {{a2, a1}, {a5}, {a4,
> a3}}, {{a2}, {a1, a5}, {a4, a3}}, {{a2, a3,
> a1}, {a4}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a3, a1, a4}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a1, a4,
> a5}}, {{a2, a3}, {a1, a4}, {a5}}, {{a2, a3}, {a1}, {a4,
> a5}}, {{a2}, {a3, a1}, {a4, a5}}, {{a2, a3,
> a1}, {a5}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a3, a1, a5}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a1, a5,
> a4}}, {{a2, a3}, {a1, a5}, {a4}}, {{a2, a3}, {a1}, {a5,
> a4}}, {{a2}, {a3, a1}, {a5, a4}}, {{a2, a3,
> a4}, {a1}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a3, a4, a1}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a4, a1,
> a5}}, {{a2, a3}, {a4, a1}, {a5}}, {{a2, a3}, {a4}, {a1,
> a5}}, {{a2}, {a3, a4}, {a1, a5}}, {{a2, a3,
> a4}, {a5}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a3, a4, a5}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a4, a5,
> a1}}, {{a2, a3}, {a4, a5}, {a1}}, {{a2, a3}, {a4}, {a5,
> a1}}, {{a2}, {a3, a4}, {a5, a1}}, {{a2, a3,
> a5}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a3, a5, a1}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a5, a1,
> a4}}, {{a2, a3}, {a5, a1}, {a4}}, {{a2, a3}, {a5}, {a1,
> a4}}, {{a2}, {a3, a5}, {a1, a4}}, {{a2, a3,
> a5}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a3, a5, a4}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a5, a4,
> a1}}, {{a2, a3}, {a5, a4}, {a1}}, {{a2, a3}, {a5}, {a4,
> a1}}, {{a2}, {a3, a5}, {a4, a1}}, {{a2, a4,
> a1}, {a3}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a4, a1, a3}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a1, a3,
> a5}}, {{a2, a4}, {a1, a3}, {a5}}, {{a2, a4}, {a1}, {a3,
> a5}}, {{a2}, {a4, a1}, {a3, a5}}, {{a2, a4,
> a1}, {a5}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a4, a1, a5}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a1, a5,
> a3}}, {{a2, a4}, {a1, a5}, {a3}}, {{a2, a4}, {a1}, {a5,
> a3}}, {{a2}, {a4, a1}, {a5, a3}}, {{a2, a4,
> a3}, {a1}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a4, a3, a1}, {a5}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a3, a1,
> a5}}, {{a2, a4}, {a3, a1}, {a5}}, {{a2, a4}, {a3}, {a1,
> a5}}, {{a2}, {a4, a3}, {a1, a5}}, {{a2, a4,
> a3}, {a5}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a4, a3, a5}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a3, a5,
> a1}}, {{a2, a4}, {a3, a5}, {a1}}, {{a2, a4}, {a3}, {a5,
> a1}}, {{a2}, {a4, a3}, {a5, a1}}, {{a2, a4,
> a5}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a4, a5, a1}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a5, a1,
> a3}}, {{a2, a4}, {a5, a1}, {a3}}, {{a2, a4}, {a5}, {a1,
> a3}}, {{a2}, {a4, a5}, {a1, a3}}, {{a2, a4,
> a5}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a4, a5, a3}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a5, a3,
> a1}}, {{a2, a4}, {a5, a3}, {a1}}, {{a2, a4}, {a5}, {a3,
> a1}}, {{a2}, {a4, a5}, {a3, a1}}, {{a2, a5,
> a1}, {a3}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a5, a1, a3}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a5}, {a1, a3,
> a4}}, {{a2, a5}, {a1, a3}, {a4}}, {{a2, a5}, {a1}, {a3,
> a4}}, {{a2}, {a5, a1}, {a3, a4}}, {{a2, a5,
> a1}, {a4}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a5, a1, a4}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a5}, {a1, a4,
> a3}}, {{a2, a5}, {a1, a4}, {a3}}, {{a2, a5}, {a1}, {a4,
> a3}}, {{a2}, {a5, a1}, {a4, a3}}, {{a2, a5,
> a3}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a5, a3, a1}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a5}, {a3, a1,
> a4}}, {{a2, a5}, {a3, a1}, {a4}}, {{a2, a5}, {a3}, {a1,
> a4}}, {{a2}, {a5, a3}, {a1, a4}}, {{a2, a5,
> a3}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a5, a3, a4}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a5}, {a3, a4,
> a1}}, {{a2, a5}, {a3, a4}, {a1}}, {{a2, a5}, {a3}, {a4,
> a1}}, {{a2}, {a5, a3}, {a4, a1}}, {{a2, a5,
> a4}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a5, a4, a1}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a5}, {a4, a1,
> a3}}, {{a2, a5}, {a4, a1}, {a3}}, {{a2, a5}, {a4}, {a1,
> a3}}, {{a2}, {a5, a4}, {a1, a3}}, {{a2, a5,
> a4}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a5, a4, a3}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a5}, {a4, a3,
> a1}}, {{a2, a5}, {a4, a3}, {a1}}, {{a2, a5}, {a4}, {a3,
> a1}}, {{a2}, {a5, a4}, {a3, a1}}, {{a3, a1,
> a2}, {a4}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a1, a2, a4}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a2, a4,
> a5}}, {{a3, a1}, {a2, a4}, {a5}}, {{a3, a1}, {a2}, {a4,
> a5}}, {{a3}, {a1, a2}, {a4, a5}}, {{a3, a1,
> a2}, {a5}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a1, a2, a5}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a2, a5,
> a4}}, {{a3, a1}, {a2, a5}, {a4}}, {{a3, a1}, {a2}, {a5,
> a4}}, {{a3}, {a1, a2}, {a5, a4}}, {{a3, a1,
> a4}, {a2}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a1, a4, a2}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a4, a2,
> a5}}, {{a3, a1}, {a4, a2}, {a5}}, {{a3, a1}, {a4}, {a2,
> a5}}, {{a3}, {a1, a4}, {a2, a5}}, {{a3, a1,
> a4}, {a5}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a1, a4, a5}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a4, a5,
> a2}}, {{a3, a1}, {a4, a5}, {a2}}, {{a3, a1}, {a4}, {a5,
> a2}}, {{a3}, {a1, a4}, {a5, a2}}, {{a3, a1,
> a5}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a1, a5, a2}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a5, a2,
> a4}}, {{a3, a1}, {a5, a2}, {a4}}, {{a3, a1}, {a5}, {a2,
> a4}}, {{a3}, {a1, a5}, {a2, a4}}, {{a3, a1,
> a5}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a1, a5, a4}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a5, a4,
> a2}}, {{a3, a1}, {a5, a4}, {a2}}, {{a3, a1}, {a5}, {a4,
> a2}}, {{a3}, {a1, a5}, {a4, a2}}, {{a3, a2,
> a1}, {a4}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a2, a1, a4}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a1, a4,
> a5}}, {{a3, a2}, {a1, a4}, {a5}}, {{a3, a2}, {a1}, {a4,
> a5}}, {{a3}, {a2, a1}, {a4, a5}}, {{a3, a2,
> a1}, {a5}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a2, a1, a5}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a1, a5,
> a4}}, {{a3, a2}, {a1, a5}, {a4}}, {{a3, a2}, {a1}, {a5,
> a4}}, {{a3}, {a2, a1}, {a5, a4}}, {{a3, a2,
> a4}, {a1}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a2, a4, a1}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a4, a1,
> a5}}, {{a3, a2}, {a4, a1}, {a5}}, {{a3, a2}, {a4}, {a1,
> a5}}, {{a3}, {a2, a4}, {a1, a5}}, {{a3, a2,
> a4}, {a5}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a2, a4, a5}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a4, a5,
> a1}}, {{a3, a2}, {a4, a5}, {a1}}, {{a3, a2}, {a4}, {a5,
> a1}}, {{a3}, {a2, a4}, {a5, a1}}, {{a3, a2,
> a5}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a2, a5, a1}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a5, a1,
> a4}}, {{a3, a2}, {a5, a1}, {a4}}, {{a3, a2}, {a5}, {a1,
> a4}}, {{a3}, {a2, a5}, {a1, a4}}, {{a3, a2,
> a5}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a2, a5, a4}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a5, a4,
> a1}}, {{a3, a2}, {a5, a4}, {a1}}, {{a3, a2}, {a5}, {a4,
> a1}}, {{a3}, {a2, a5}, {a4, a1}}, {{a3, a4,
> a1}, {a2}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a4, a1, a2}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a1, a2,
> a5}}, {{a3, a4}, {a1, a2}, {a5}}, {{a3, a4}, {a1}, {a2,
> a5}}, {{a3}, {a4, a1}, {a2, a5}}, {{a3, a4,
> a1}, {a5}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a4, a1, a5}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a1, a5,
> a2}}, {{a3, a4}, {a1, a5}, {a2}}, {{a3, a4}, {a1}, {a5,
> a2}}, {{a3}, {a4, a1}, {a5, a2}}, {{a3, a4,
> a2}, {a1}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a4, a2, a1}, {a5}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a2, a1,
> a5}}, {{a3, a4}, {a2, a1}, {a5}}, {{a3, a4}, {a2}, {a1,
> a5}}, {{a3}, {a4, a2}, {a1, a5}}, {{a3, a4,
> a2}, {a5}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a4, a2, a5}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a2, a5,
> a1}}, {{a3, a4}, {a2, a5}, {a1}}, {{a3, a4}, {a2}, {a5,
> a1}}, {{a3}, {a4, a2}, {a5, a1}}, {{a3, a4,
> a5}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a4, a5, a1}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a5, a1,
> a2}}, {{a3, a4}, {a5, a1}, {a2}}, {{a3, a4}, {a5}, {a1,
> a2}}, {{a3}, {a4, a5}, {a1, a2}}, {{a3, a4,
> a5}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a4, a5, a2}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a5, a2,
> a1}}, {{a3, a4}, {a5, a2}, {a1}}, {{a3, a4}, {a5}, {a2,
> a1}}, {{a3}, {a4, a5}, {a2, a1}}, {{a3, a5,
> a1}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a5, a1, a2}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a5}, {a1, a2,
> a4}}, {{a3, a5}, {a1, a2}, {a4}}, {{a3, a5}, {a1}, {a2,
> a4}}, {{a3}, {a5, a1}, {a2, a4}}, {{a3, a5,
> a1}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a5, a1, a4}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a5}, {a1, a4,
> a2}}, {{a3, a5}, {a1, a4}, {a2}}, {{a3, a5}, {a1}, {a4,
> a2}}, {{a3}, {a5, a1}, {a4, a2}}, {{a3, a5,
> a2}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a5, a2, a1}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a5}, {a2, a1,
> a4}}, {{a3, a5}, {a2, a1}, {a4}}, {{a3, a5}, {a2}, {a1,
> a4}}, {{a3}, {a5, a2}, {a1, a4}}, {{a3, a5,
> a2}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a5, a2, a4}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a5}, {a2, a4,
> a1}}, {{a3, a5}, {a2, a4}, {a1}}, {{a3, a5}, {a2}, {a4,
> a1}}, {{a3}, {a5, a2}, {a4, a1}}, {{a3, a5,
> a4}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a5, a4, a1}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a5}, {a4, a1,
> a2}}, {{a3, a5}, {a4, a1}, {a2}}, {{a3, a5}, {a4}, {a1,
> a2}}, {{a3}, {a5, a4}, {a1, a2}}, {{a3, a5,
> a4}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a5, a4, a2}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a5}, {a4, a2,
> a1}}, {{a3, a5}, {a4, a2}, {a1}}, {{a3, a5}, {a4}, {a2,
> a1}}, {{a3}, {a5, a4}, {a2, a1}}, {{a4, a1,
> a2}, {a3}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a1, a2, a3}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a2, a3,
> a5}}, {{a4, a1}, {a2, a3}, {a5}}, {{a4, a1}, {a2}, {a3,
> a5}}, {{a4}, {a1, a2}, {a3, a5}}, {{a4, a1,
> a2}, {a5}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a1, a2, a5}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a2, a5,
> a3}}, {{a4, a1}, {a2, a5}, {a3}}, {{a4, a1}, {a2}, {a5,
> a3}}, {{a4}, {a1, a2}, {a5, a3}}, {{a4, a1,
> a3}, {a2}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a1, a3, a2}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a3, a2,
> a5}}, {{a4, a1}, {a3, a2}, {a5}}, {{a4, a1}, {a3}, {a2,
> a5}}, {{a4}, {a1, a3}, {a2, a5}}, {{a4, a1,
> a3}, {a5}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a1, a3, a5}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a3, a5,
> a2}}, {{a4, a1}, {a3, a5}, {a2}}, {{a4, a1}, {a3}, {a5,
> a2}}, {{a4}, {a1, a3}, {a5, a2}}, {{a4, a1,
> a5}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a1, a5, a2}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a5, a2,
> a3}}, {{a4, a1}, {a5, a2}, {a3}}, {{a4, a1}, {a5}, {a2,
> a3}}, {{a4}, {a1, a5}, {a2, a3}}, {{a4, a1,
> a5}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a1, a5, a3}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a5, a3,
> a2}}, {{a4, a1}, {a5, a3}, {a2}}, {{a4, a1}, {a5}, {a3,
> a2}}, {{a4}, {a1, a5}, {a3, a2}}, {{a4, a2,
> a1}, {a3}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a2, a1, a3}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a1, a3,
> a5}}, {{a4, a2}, {a1, a3}, {a5}}, {{a4, a2}, {a1}, {a3,
> a5}}, {{a4}, {a2, a1}, {a3, a5}}, {{a4, a2,
> a1}, {a5}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a2, a1, a5}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a1, a5,
> a3}}, {{a4, a2}, {a1, a5}, {a3}}, {{a4, a2}, {a1}, {a5,
> a3}}, {{a4}, {a2, a1}, {a5, a3}}, {{a4, a2,
> a3}, {a1}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a2, a3, a1}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a3, a1,
> a5}}, {{a4, a2}, {a3, a1}, {a5}}, {{a4, a2}, {a3}, {a1,
> a5}}, {{a4}, {a2, a3}, {a1, a5}}, {{a4, a2,
> a3}, {a5}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a2, a3, a5}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a3, a5,
> a1}}, {{a4, a2}, {a3, a5}, {a1}}, {{a4, a2}, {a3}, {a5,
> a1}}, {{a4}, {a2, a3}, {a5, a1}}, {{a4, a2,
> a5}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a2, a5, a1}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a5, a1,
> a3}}, {{a4, a2}, {a5, a1}, {a3}}, {{a4, a2}, {a5}, {a1,
> a3}}, {{a4}, {a2, a5}, {a1, a3}}, {{a4, a2,
> a5}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a2, a5, a3}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a5, a3,
> a1}}, {{a4, a2}, {a5, a3}, {a1}}, {{a4, a2}, {a5}, {a3,
> a1}}, {{a4}, {a2, a5}, {a3, a1}}, {{a4, a3,
> a1}, {a2}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a3, a1, a2}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a1, a2,
> a5}}, {{a4, a3}, {a1, a2}, {a5}}, {{a4, a3}, {a1}, {a2,
> a5}}, {{a4}, {a3, a1}, {a2, a5}}, {{a4, a3,
> a1}, {a5}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a3, a1, a5}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a1, a5,
> a2}}, {{a4, a3}, {a1, a5}, {a2}}, {{a4, a3}, {a1}, {a5,
> a2}}, {{a4}, {a3, a1}, {a5, a2}}, {{a4, a3,
> a2}, {a1}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a3, a2, a1}, {a5}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a2, a1,
> a5}}, {{a4, a3}, {a2, a1}, {a5}}, {{a4, a3}, {a2}, {a1,
> a5}}, {{a4}, {a3, a2}, {a1, a5}}, {{a4, a3,
> a2}, {a5}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a3, a2, a5}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a2, a5,
> a1}}, {{a4, a3}, {a2, a5}, {a1}}, {{a4, a3}, {a2}, {a5,
> a1}}, {{a4}, {a3, a2}, {a5, a1}}, {{a4, a3,
> a5}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a3, a5, a1}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a5, a1,
> a2}}, {{a4, a3}, {a5, a1}, {a2}}, {{a4, a3}, {a5}, {a1,
> a2}}, {{a4}, {a3, a5}, {a1, a2}}, {{a4, a3,
> a5}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a3, a5, a2}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a5, a2,
> a1}}, {{a4, a3}, {a5, a2}, {a1}}, {{a4, a3}, {a5}, {a2,
> a1}}, {{a4}, {a3, a5}, {a2, a1}}, {{a4, a5,
> a1}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a5, a1, a2}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a5}, {a1, a2,
> a3}}, {{a4, a5}, {a1, a2}, {a3}}, {{a4, a5}, {a1}, {a2,
> a3}}, {{a4}, {a5, a1}, {a2, a3}}, {{a4, a5,
> a1}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a5, a1, a3}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a5}, {a1, a3,
> a2}}, {{a4, a5}, {a1, a3}, {a2}}, {{a4, a5}, {a1}, {a3,
> a2}}, {{a4}, {a5, a1}, {a3, a2}}, {{a4, a5,
> a2}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a5, a2, a1}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a5}, {a2, a1,
> a3}}, {{a4, a5}, {a2, a1}, {a3}}, {{a4, a5}, {a2}, {a1,
> a3}}, {{a4}, {a5, a2}, {a1, a3}}, {{a4, a5,
> a2}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a5, a2, a3}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a5}, {a2, a3,
> a1}}, {{a4, a5}, {a2, a3}, {a1}}, {{a4, a5}, {a2}, {a3,
> a1}}, {{a4}, {a5, a2}, {a3, a1}}, {{a4, a5,
> a3}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a5, a3, a1}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a5}, {a3, a1,
> a2}}, {{a4, a5}, {a3, a1}, {a2}}, {{a4, a5}, {a3}, {a1,
> a2}}, {{a4}, {a5, a3}, {a1, a2}}, {{a4, a5,
> a3}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a5, a3, a2}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a5}, {a3, a2,
> a1}}, {{a4, a5}, {a3, a2}, {a1}}, {{a4, a5}, {a3}, {a2,
> a1}}, {{a4}, {a5, a3}, {a2, a1}}, {{a5, a1,
> a2}, {a3}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a1, a2, a3}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a1}, {a2, a3,
> a4}}, {{a5, a1}, {a2, a3}, {a4}}, {{a5, a1}, {a2}, {a3,
> a4}}, {{a5}, {a1, a2}, {a3, a4}}, {{a5, a1,
> a2}, {a4}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a1, a2, a4}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a1}, {a2, a4,
> a3}}, {{a5, a1}, {a2, a4}, {a3}}, {{a5, a1}, {a2}, {a4,
> a3}}, {{a5}, {a1, a2}, {a4, a3}}, {{a5, a1,
> a3}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a1, a3, a2}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a1}, {a3, a2,
> a4}}, {{a5, a1}, {a3, a2}, {a4}}, {{a5, a1}, {a3}, {a2,
> a4}}, {{a5}, {a1, a3}, {a2, a4}}, {{a5, a1,
> a3}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a1, a3, a4}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a1}, {a3, a4,
> a2}}, {{a5, a1}, {a3, a4}, {a2}}, {{a5, a1}, {a3}, {a4,
> a2}}, {{a5}, {a1, a3}, {a4, a2}}, {{a5, a1,
> a4}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a1, a4, a2}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a1}, {a4, a2,
> a3}}, {{a5, a1}, {a4, a2}, {a3}}, {{a5, a1}, {a4}, {a2,
> a3}}, {{a5}, {a1, a4}, {a2, a3}}, {{a5, a1,
> a4}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a1, a4, a3}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a1}, {a4, a3,
> a2}}, {{a5, a1}, {a4, a3}, {a2}}, {{a5, a1}, {a4}, {a3,
> a2}}, {{a5}, {a1, a4}, {a3, a2}}, {{a5, a2,
> a1}, {a3}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a2, a1, a3}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a2}, {a1, a3,
> a4}}, {{a5, a2}, {a1, a3}, {a4}}, {{a5, a2}, {a1}, {a3,
> a4}}, {{a5}, {a2, a1}, {a3, a4}}, {{a5, a2,
> a1}, {a4}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a2, a1, a4}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a2}, {a1, a4,
> a3}}, {{a5, a2}, {a1, a4}, {a3}}, {{a5, a2}, {a1}, {a4,
> a3}}, {{a5}, {a2, a1}, {a4, a3}}, {{a5, a2,
> a3}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a2, a3, a1}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a2}, {a3, a1,
> a4}}, {{a5, a2}, {a3, a1}, {a4}}, {{a5, a2}, {a3}, {a1,
> a4}}, {{a5}, {a2, a3}, {a1, a4}}, {{a5, a2,
> a3}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a2, a3, a4}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a2}, {a3, a4,
> a1}}, {{a5, a2}, {a3, a4}, {a1}}, {{a5, a2}, {a3}, {a4,
> a1}}, {{a5}, {a2, a3}, {a4, a1}}, {{a5, a2,
> a4}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a2, a4, a1}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a2}, {a4, a1,
> a3}}, {{a5, a2}, {a4, a1}, {a3}}, {{a5, a2}, {a4}, {a1,
> a3}}, {{a5}, {a2, a4}, {a1, a3}}, {{a5, a2,
> a4}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a2, a4, a3}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a2}, {a4, a3,
> a1}}, {{a5, a2}, {a4, a3}, {a1}}, {{a5, a2}, {a4}, {a3,
> a1}}, {{a5}, {a2, a4}, {a3, a1}}, {{a5, a3,
> a1}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a3, a1, a2}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a3}, {a1, a2,
> a4}}, {{a5, a3}, {a1, a2}, {a4}}, {{a5, a3}, {a1}, {a2,
> a4}}, {{a5}, {a3, a1}, {a2, a4}}, {{a5, a3,
> a1}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a3, a1, a4}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a3}, {a1, a4,
> a2}}, {{a5, a3}, {a1, a4}, {a2}}, {{a5, a3}, {a1}, {a4,
> a2}}, {{a5}, {a3, a1}, {a4, a2}}, {{a5, a3,
> a2}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a3, a2, a1}, {a4}}, {{a5}, {a3}, {a2, a1,
> a4}}, {{a5, a3}, {a2, a1}, {a4}}, {{a5, a3}, {a2}, {a1,
> a4}}, {{a5}, {a3, a2}, {a1, a4}}, {{a5, a3,
> a2}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a3, a2, a4}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a3}, {a2, a4,
> a1}}, {{a5, a3}, {a2, a4}, {a1}}, {{a5, a3}, {a2}, {a4,
> a1}}, {{a5}, {a3, a2}, {a4, a1}}, {{a5, a3,
> a4}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a3, a4, a1}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a3}, {a4, a1,
> a2}}, {{a5, a3}, {a4, a1}, {a2}}, {{a5, a3}, {a4}, {a1,
> a2}}, {{a5}, {a3, a4}, {a1, a2}}, {{a5, a3,
> a4}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a3, a4, a2}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a3}, {a4, a2,
> a1}}, {{a5, a3}, {a4, a2}, {a1}}, {{a5, a3}, {a4}, {a2,
> a1}}, {{a5}, {a3, a4}, {a2, a1}}, {{a5, a4,
> a1}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a4, a1, a2}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a4}, {a1, a2,
> a3}}, {{a5, a4}, {a1, a2}, {a3}}, {{a5, a4}, {a1}, {a2,
> a3}}, {{a5}, {a4, a1}, {a2, a3}}, {{a5, a4,
> a1}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a4, a1, a3}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a4}, {a1, a3,
> a2}}, {{a5, a4}, {a1, a3}, {a2}}, {{a5, a4}, {a1}, {a3,
> a2}}, {{a5}, {a4, a1}, {a3, a2}}, {{a5, a4,
> a2}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a4, a2, a1}, {a3}}, {{a5}, {a4}, {a2, a1,
> a3}}, {{a5, a4}, {a2, a1}, {a3}}, {{a5, a4}, {a2}, {a1,
> a3}}, {{a5}, {a4, a2}, {a1, a3}}, {{a5, a4,
> a2}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a4, a2, a3}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a4}, {a2, a3,
> a1}}, {{a5, a4}, {a2, a3}, {a1}}, {{a5, a4}, {a2}, {a3,
> a1}}, {{a5}, {a4, a2}, {a3, a1}}, {{a5, a4,
> a3}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a4, a3, a1}, {a2}}, {{a5}, {a4}, {a3, a1,
> a2}}, {{a5, a4}, {a3, a1}, {a2}}, {{a5, a4}, {a3}, {a1,
> a2}}, {{a5}, {a4, a3}, {a1, a2}}, {{a5, a4,
> a3}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a4, a3, a2}, {a1}}, {{a5}, {a4}, {a3, a2,
> a1}}, {{a5, a4}, {a3, a2}, {a1}}, {{a5, a4}, {a3}, {a2,
> a1}}, {{a5}, {a4, a3}, {a2, a1}}}

there are 720 elements but among them I want to treat my $\{ \{a1,a2,a3\}, \{a4\}, \{a5\} \} = \{ \{a2,a1, a3\}, \{a4\}, \{a5\} \} =  \{ \{a3,a1, a2\}, \{a4\}, \{a5\} \}= \cdots$, i.e., I want to treat the elements of $a1a2a3 = a2a3a1=a3a2a1=...$ I mean treat different $6$ operator as one.  Furthermore the (2,2,1) decomposition $\{\{a1,a2\}, \{a3,a4\}, \{a5\} \} = \{ \{a2,a1\}, \{a3,a4\}, \{a5\} \} = \{ \{a1,a2\}, \{a4,a3\}, \{a5\} \}= ..$ and produce my full list.

For example, after explicit computation, I know for the above set there are 150 elements of my total set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alist = {{{a1, a2}, {a3}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a2, 
     a3}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a2}, {a3, a4}}, {{a1, 
     a2}, {a4}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a2, a4}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a2}, {a4, 
     a3}}, {{a1, a3}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a3, 
     a2}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a2, a4}}, {{a1, 
     a3}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a3, a4}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a4, 
     a2}}, {{a1, a4}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a4, 
     a2}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a2, a3}}, {{a1, 
     a4}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a4, a3}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a3, 
     a2}}, {{a2, a1}, {a3}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a1, 
     a3}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a3, a4}}, {{a2, 
     a1}, {a4}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a1, a4}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a4, 
     a3}}, {{a2, a3}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a3, 
     a1}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a1, a4}}, {{a2, 
     a3}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a3, a4}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a4, 
     a1}}, {{a2, a4}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a4, 
     a1}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a1, a3}}, {{a2, 
     a4}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a4, a3}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a3, 
     a1}}, {{a3, a1}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a1, 
     a2}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a2, a4}}, {{a3, 
     a1}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a1, a4}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a4, 
     a2}}, {{a3, a2}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a2, 
     a1}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a1, a4}}, {{a3, 
     a2}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a2, a4}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a4, 
     a1}}, {{a3, a4}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a4, 
     a1}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a1, a2}}, {{a3, 
     a4}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a4, a2}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a2, 
     a1}}, {{a4, a1}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a1, 
     a2}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a2, a3}}, {{a4, 
     a1}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a1, a3}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a3, 
     a2}}, {{a4, a2}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a2, 
     a1}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a1, a3}}, {{a4, 
     a2}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a2, a3}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a3, 
     a1}}, {{a4, a3}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a3, 
     a1}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a1, a2}}, {{a4, 
     a3}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a3, a2}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a2, 
     a1}}};
```

---

```
blist = DeleteDuplicatesBy[alist, Sort /@ # &]
```

---

> {{a1}, {a2, a4}, {a3}}, {{a1, a3}, {a2}, {a4}}, {{a1}, {a3}, {a2,
> a4}}, {{a1, a3}, {a4}, {a2}}, {{a1}, {a3, a4}, {a2}}, {{a1,
> a4}, {a2}, {a3}}, {{a1}, {a4}, {a2, a3}}, {{a1,
> a4}, {a3}, {a2}}, {{a2}, {a1, a3}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a1}, {a3,
> a4}}, {{a2}, {a1, a4}, {a3}}, {{a2,
> a3}, {a1}, {a4}}, {{a2}, {a3}, {a1, a4}}, {{a2,
> a3}, {a4}, {a1}}, {{a2}, {a3, a4}, {a1}}, {{a2,
> a4}, {a1}, {a3}}, {{a2}, {a4}, {a1, a3}}, {{a2,
> a4}, {a3}, {a1}}, {{a3}, {a1, a2}, {a4}}, {{a3}, {a1}, {a2,
> a4}}, {{a3}, {a1, a4}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a2}, {a1, a4}}, {{a3}, {a2,
> a4}, {a1}}, {{a3, a4}, {a1}, {a2}}, {{a3}, {a4}, {a1, a2}}, {{a3,
> a4}, {a2}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a1, a2}, {a3}}, {{a4}, {a1}, {a2,
> a3}}, {{a4}, {a1, a3}, {a2}}, {{a4}, {a2}, {a1, a3}}, {{a4}, {a2,
> a3}, {a1}}, {{a4}, {a3}, {a1, a2}}}

```
Length@blist (* 36 *)
```

Same drill for the next set, where the `Length` comes to 150.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you might want to get the final list directly, you can simply take the permutations of each k-set-partition of the ground list as follows:

Use the resource function [KSetPartitions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/KSetPartitions/) to get the desired partitions and permute each partition:

```
kSP = ResourceFunction["KSetPartitions"];

kspPermutations[a_List, k_Integer] := Join @@ (Permutations /@ kSP[a, k])


Length @ kspPermutations[{a1, a2, a3, a4}, 3]
```

> ```
> 36
> ```

```
Length @ kspPermutations[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}, 3]
```

> ```
> 150
> ```

Naming the first and second lists in OP `t43` and `t53`, respectively, `kspPermutations` gives the same results as the method in Syed's answer:

```
Sort[kspPermutations[{a1, a2, a3, a4}, 3]] == 
   Sort[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Map[Sort]] @ t43]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Sort[kspPermutations[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}, 3]] == 
   Sort[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Map[Sort]] @ t53]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Grid[Table[Length @  kspPermutations[Range@i, #] & /@ Range[i], {i, 1, 10}] //
    MapIndexed[Prepend[#2[[1]]]@# &, #] & // Prepend[Prepend[Range[10], ""]], 
   Dividers -> {{All, 2 -> Red}, {All, 2 -> Red}}] // 
  Labeled[#, {"k", "n"}, {Top, Left}] & // Panel
```

[image]